# How do I apply cufon.js only for Internet Explorer, in template.php?

Tags: theming, javascript

I have some font problems in Internet Explorer, so I am trying to apply `font-family` through JavaScript. It works, but the JavaScript code runs for every browser.

How do I run JavaScript code only on Internet Explorer?

This my code.

```
drupal_add_js('sites/all/themes/blogbuzz/js/cufon-yui.js');
drupal_add_js('sites/all/themes/blogbuzz/js/Helvetica_CE_35_Thin_100.font.js');
drupal_add_js('(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    Cufon.replace("#content-header");
    Cufon.replace("#client_tle");
    Cufon.replace("#block-block-16");     
  });
})(jQuery)', "inline");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply JS only to one browser using Drupal functions. What you can do is:

- CSS workaround:

  - apply CSS only to IE
  - assign some style that will not be visible, but also will not be present in non-IE, like white 1px border on white background
  - use [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) jQuery method to test if element has property you expect it to have in IE, and if true, execute your code.
- JavaScript way:
  Use [jQuery Browser Plugin](http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/) or similar solution to identify browser inside your js file. Execute your code if it's the browser you need it executed in.

Comment: It is possible,i got the answer

Comment: @user2775188 if you know how, then share. You can answer your own question. In Drupal, `$options` for [`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) does not support `browsers` element. It's OK only in [`drupal_add_css()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7). HTML on it's own does not provide functionality like that, either.

Comment: You can use $.browser.msie variable of jQuery. Remember to use that with jQuery Migrate if you are using jQuery 1.9+.

$(document).ready(function()
{
   if($.browser.msie){
          Cufon.replace("#content-header");
          Cufon.replace("#client_tle");
          Cufon.replace("#block-block-16");  
   }
});

Comment: @user2775188 that's exactly what my second bullet says: use javascript file on all browsers, and inside it test with jQuery if it's IE or not. Only difference is that I suggested other plugin. Of course feel free to add your own answer :)

Comment: _You can't apply JS only to one browser_ do you mean in Drupal only? Doing it the 'normal' way is very easy: `<!--[if IE]> <script src="..."></script> <![endif]-->`

Comment: @Clive Sorry for my lack of precision, I wrote it in Drupal context. Corrected

Comment: Looks like someone's had a go at making Conditional Comments able to do it via the info file: https://drupal.org/node/639288

Comment: @Clive pretty useless in IE 10 anyway, [it seems](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/07/06/html5-parsing-in-ie10.aspx). "conditional comments can still be used, but will only target older versions of IE".

Comment: Very good point...

Answer (score -1):

Something like this is what you are looking for:

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  // Add conditional stylesheets for IE
  drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/css/ie8style.css', array(
    'group' => CSS_THEME,
    'browsers' => array(
      'IE' => 'lte IE 8',
      '!IE' => FALSE,
     ),
    'every_page' => TRUE,
    'weight' => 10,
   )
  );
}
```

Comment: There is no equivalent for JS.

Comment: You can use $.browser.msie variable of jQuery. Remember to use that with jQuery Migrate if you are using jQuery 1.9+.

$(document).ready(function()
{
   if($.browser.msie){
          Cufon.replace("#content-header");
          Cufon.replace("#client_tle");
          Cufon.replace("#block-block-16");  
   }
});